# CSS "Sticky Footer" with additonal wrapper div

Tags: html, css, ember.js

## Introduction

There are many good and well tested recipes for a footer that is always as the bottom of a page but is not fixed (or overlap content). Here is one that works for me: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

In short it works like follows:

HTML:

```
<html><body>
  <div id="wrapper>SOME CONTENT</div><footer></footer>
</body></html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto -4em;
}
footer {
  height: 4em;
}
```

The trick is that `#wrapper` is forced to use 100% of available height, but is margin bottom leaves some space for a footer (negative margin is exactly the size of the footer).

## Problem description

While building a Single Page Application, some javascripts frameworks like **Ember.js** adds additional divs to our document structure (for example to handle events). This creates an addtional wrapper around our original document which may look like this:

```
<html><body>
  <div class="framework-container">
    <div id="wrapper>SOME CONTENT</div><footer></footer>
  </div>
</body></html>
```

This additional `div` breaks our CSS setup. To improve the situation we want to say that `framework-container` should behave exactly as `body`, so we may try to add:

```
.framework-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

**And it almost work: if the content is smaller than the page height. Otherwise there is a noticeable distance between the footer and bottom of the page - which we cannot accept.**

Does anyone know a pure CSS solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you said the wrapper worked or not, but you can tell Ember to insert the application into a particular element, and it won't insert any elements outside(above) that element.

**Set the root Element**

```
App = Em.Application.create({
  rootElement: '#body'
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">I'm a header</div>
  <div id="body"></div>
  <div id="footer">I'm a footer</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,
body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:100%;
}
#container {
   min-height:100%;
   position:relative;
}
#header {
   background:#ff0;
   padding:10px;
}
#body {
   padding:10px;
   padding-bottom:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
}
#footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
   background:#6cf;
}
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OPaguRU/1/edit

I totally jacked some of this from: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

Comment: does it mean I can say `rootElement: "body"` and Ember will not create any additional 'top` hierarchy div above those I define in my templates?

Comment: body is the default for the rootElement.  I just figured out what you were saying at the bottom, so I might be leading you astray with my comment.  What I said is true, but I'm not sure if this will help you.

Comment: with ember particularly, the issue is created by application view that adds its div and wraps all outlets we have control upon. Wonder if we can say:  `App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({ tagName: "script" })`

Comment: Checked my last comment - it does not work, at least in my quite obsolete setup with ember 1.0.0-pre2

Comment: Try out this.  Ember 1.0 has been out for a while, and you should hop up as soon as you can, there were some major changes and fixes.

Comment: Your jsbin is working good because it uses document structure described in the "introduction". The issue starts if you want the entire content of body to be rendered by Ember.js. ATM you can control only the content of `#body` and cannot change footer or header from Ember (at least without hacks :-) ). (PS. I'm using new ember is other project and will eventually use also in this one, but it requires to replace router entirely so it will take some time)

Comment: The CSS setup is a bit different. I will give a try. Thanks for all the efforts.